# PC HD Video Card Radeon Passive Cooling No display when hardware installed

Tags: video, graphics-card

Hi guys i'm noob to computer hardware, i attached my Video card to the motherboard, but it's not displaying anything, do you guys know what i'm missing here, does this video card requires separate power cable? i tried to look for any power outlet on the video card, non says power... i lost it's manual :( help please

here's my video card,

http://content.hwigroup.net/images/products/xl/002281/2/club_3d_radeon_hd_2600_pro_passive_cooling.jpg